# Calculating maximum CPU over a given time frame Python

Tags: python-3.x, cpu

I am trying to calculate maximum CPU percentage over a given time frame. At first I tried using psutil, but this only gives me a snapshot of time. What I am trying to do is run a python script and until I end the script, can return the maximum CPU percentage over that time frame. Is this possible? Any suggestions help

```
cpu_time = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=1,percpu=False)
maxcpu = 0
    while True: 
        if cpu_time > maxcpu:
            maxcpu = cpu_time
            cpu_time = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=1,percpu=False)
            print("MAX CPU: " +str(maxcpu))
        elif maxcpu > cpu_time:
            maxcpu = maxcpu
            cpu_time = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=1,percpu=False)
            print("MAX CPU: " +str(maxcpu))
```

The code I have currently runs the loop checking to see if the maximum CPU percentage changes. I am struggling trying to break it and then have that value stored in a variable.